# How to extract the url of news articles from a website?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to extract the url of all news articles from a website. Here is what I have done:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url1 = "https://www.wsj.com/search/term.html?KEYWORDS=apple&mod=searchresults_viewallresults"
r1 = requests.get(url1)
coverpage = r1.content
soup1 = BeautifulSoup(coverpage, 'html5lib')
coverpage_news = soup1.find_all("h3", class_="headline")
coverpage_news['href']
```

But no results, any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use selenium with PhantomJS to load page and then scrape it

```
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
import requests
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By


url = 'https://www.wsj.com/search/term.html?KEYWORDS=apple&mod=searchresults_viewallresults'
browser = webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path='D:/Programowanie/phantomjs-2.1.1-windows/bin/phantomjs.exe')
browser.get(url)
element = WebDriverWait(browser, 3)
html = browser.page_source
page_soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html5lib')

coverpage_news = page_soup.find_all("h3", class_="headline")

for news in coverpage_news:
    # print(news)
    news_soap = BeautifulSoup(str(news), 'html.parser')
    for a in news_soap.find_all('a', href=True): 
        print(a['href'])
```

Result:

```
/articles/the-stock-market-is-a-strong-election-day-predictor-11599490800?mod=searchresults&page=1&pos=1
/articles/remote-schools-hidden-cost-parents-quit-work-to-teach-prompting-new-recession-woes-11599487201?mod=searchresults&page=1&pos=2
/articles/why-billy-porter-takes-breaks-from-the-news-11599481884?mod=searchresults&page=1&pos=3
/articles/sudden-volatility-in-tech-stocks-unnerves-investors-11599471001?mod=searchresults&page=1&pos=4
/articles/samsung-verizon-sign-6-65-billion-5g-contract-11599469883?mod=searchresults&page=1&pos=5
/articles/where-danger-lurks-in-the-big-tech-rally-11599397200?mod=searchresults&page=1&pos=6
/articles/fortnite-maker-asks-judge-again-to-return-game-to-apples-app-store-11599319938?mod=searchresults&page=1&pos=7
/articles/united-airlines-draftkings-facebook-stocks-that-defined-the-week-11599261143?mod=searchresults&page=1&pos=8
/articles/starved-for-sports-viewers-flock-to-nba-nhl-11599259896?mod=searchresults&page=1&pos=9
/articles/global-stock-markets-dow-update-9-04-2020-11599192206?mod=searchresults&page=1&pos=10
/articles/most-businesses-were-unprepared-for-covid-19-dominos-delivered-11599234424?mod=searchresults&page=1&pos=11
/articles/readers-favorite-summer-recipes-11599238648?mod=searchresults&page=1&pos=12
/articles/softbanks-bet-on-tech-giants-fueled-powerful-market-rally-11599232205?mod=searchresults&page=1&pos=13
/articles/juul-shelves-plan-for-feature-that-counts-puffs-11599211801?mod=searchresults&page=1&pos=14
/articles/apple-still-wears-the-market-crown-it-can-easily-slip-11599231617?mod=searchresults&page=1&pos=15
/articles/eat-a-peach-review-pressure-cooker-11599229971?mod=searchresults&page=1&pos=16
/articles/starting-can-be-the-hardest-part-11599229216?mod=searchresults&page=1&pos=17
/articles/bumbles-buzz-wont-sting-match-11599217202?mod=searchresults&page=1&pos=18
/articles/how-options-market-amateurs-might-have-tripped-up-big-tech-11599213817?mod=searchresults&page=1&pos=19
/articles/global-stock-markets-dow-update-9-03-2020-11599125940?mod=searchresults&page=1&pos=20
```

Answer (score 0):

Page displays headers even if I turn off `JavaScript` in web browser so it can be scraped without `Selenium` but you have 3 problems/mistakes.

**First:** this server checks header `User-Agent`

```
headers = {
    "User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:80.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/80.0"
}

url = "https://www.wsj.com/search/term.html?KEYWORDS=apple&mod=searchresults_viewallresults"

r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
```

**Second:** `coverpage_news` is a list so you have to use `for`-loop

```
for item in coverpage_news:
    print(item)
```

**Third:** `href` is not in `<h3>` but in `<a>` which is inside `<h3>` so you have to get `.a`

```
for item in coverpage_news:
    print(item.a['href'])
```

---

Minimal working code

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

headers = {
    "User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:80.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/80.0"
}

url = "https://www.wsj.com/search/term.html?KEYWORDS=apple&mod=searchresults_viewallresults"
r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html5lib')

print('--- using find ---')

coverpage_news = soup.find_all("h3", class_="headline")
for item in coverpage_news:
    print(item.a['href'])

print('--- using CSS selector ---')

coverpage_news = soup.select("h3.headline a")
for a in coverpage_news:
    print(a['href'])
```

---

**BTW:** I tested code with `'lxml'` and `'html.parser'` instead of `'html5lib'` and `'html.parser'` couldn't find elements in HTML. It shows that parsers works different and sometimes it can make problem.